# Create directory with ARGV

Tags: ruby, argv

I created this program to create a folder in the program directory if there is an ARGV when i run the program with the command line but i can't find any folder created. i know i don't put right together my method. any idea ?

```rb
def check_if_user_gave_input
    abort("mkdir: missing input") if ARGV.empty?
end


def get_folder_name
    return folder_name = ARGV.first
end


def create_folder(name)
    Dir.mkdir(name)
end


def put_together
    folder_name = create_folder(name)
end

put_together
```

Comment: Inside `put_together`, change the call to `create_folder(name)` to `create_folder(get_folder_name)`. Currently, the variable `name` will be undefined with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting an answer so the question can get marked as solved.

in the following, `name` is undefined:

```
def put_together
    folder_name = create_folder(name)
end
```

Instead, call the method you defined `get_folder_name`

```
def put_together
    folder_name = get_folder_name
    create_folder(folder_name)
end
```